# Crear DataFrame a partir de una lista

Tags: python, lista, dataframe

Tengo dos DataFrame, mir primer DataFrame es la lista de alumnos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi DataFrame con las calificaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podemos ver no hay calificaciones de alumnos están en mi lista por lo que tengo que validar.
En un principio yo hacia esto:

```
    cedula = input('Ingrese cedula')
    nombre= input('Ingrese nombre')
    materia = input('Ingrese materia')
    calificación = input('Ingrese materia')
```

Pero al ser muchos estudiantes quiero que esos argumentos sean sustituidos por una lista, que en este caso estaría en mi segundo DataFrame, es decir quiero extraer los datos para que estos sean los de mi nueva función.

pero al momento de querer compararlos con el método siguiente:

```
    def resultado_final(cedula, materia, calificacion):
        df = pd.concat([cedula, materia,calificacion], axis=1)
```

y querer compararlos con los objetos me sale el siguiente mensaje:

```
    Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), 
    a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

por lo que me gustaría saber como poder extraer los datos de mi DataFrame y que estos sean sustituidos por los input() para así pasar argumentos como datos a mi función y esta funcione correctamente. Si es necesario convertir a entrada los datos del DataFrame o cual sería una manera rápida y eficiente. Para poder realizarlo.

Yo tengo una lista de objetos con mis lista de alumnos que contiene la información de mi primer DataFrame:

```
ListaAlumnos = []
def resultado(self,cedula,materia, calificacion)
    for alumnos in self.listaAlumnos:
        if alumnos.cedula == cedula and alumnos.cedula == materia:
            return ( cedula, materia, calificacion)
```

ahora bien yo hasta aquí voy bien y obtengo el resultado que espero pero esto cuando ingreso por teclado, por lo que yo quiero ingresar una lista en Excel o un DataFrame, para hacerlo mas rápido y que al final cree un nuevo Excel o DataFrame con los alumnos que encontró pero que haya recorrido mi lista.

Al final lo que importa entender es como sustituir los inputs() por una lista y pasar los argumentos.

Comment: Gracias por la información! Pregunta, antes de responder, por que no utilizas directamente el DataFrame original, en lugar de crear uno nuevo? Quieres cargar solo algunas columnas y no todas? Por que no le veo mucho sentido crear una lista a partir de un DataFrame para volver a crear un Dataframe.

Comment: Si de hecho mi idea es solo obtener la "Cedula", "Materia" y "Calificación", es decir que estos sean mis argumentos y pasarlos a una función que espere estos 3 argumentos. La idea en un principio era con un "input", pero quiero poder ingresar una lista como se ve en el DF original y así poder decir si fue aprobado o reprobado sin tener que hacerlo uno por uno. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías agregar lo que dijiste a la pregunta por favor? Gracias a que aclaraste eso, te puedo ofrecer una mejor forma de lograr lo que buscas.

Comment: Tu problema se puede solucionar de una forma más simple. Aparte tu error es que con cada dato de la lista `resultado` creas un dataframe, debes quitar ese `for` (el que crea el dataframe) y simplemente hacer `pd.DataFrame(resultado)`

Comment: Agregue un poco mas de lo que quiero hacer para evitar entrar datos por teclado y así ingresar todos los datos que el DataFrame contiene, y finalmente generar un DataFrame con el resultado de cada uno. En verdad muchas gracias.

Comment: En el dataframe final solo quieres las columnas `cedula`, `materia` y `calificación`?

Comment: Si, la idea es evitar ingresar dato por dato. Pero si se pueden tener todos los datos estaría mejor,

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de la salida que esperas?  como estas comparando los datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer lo que necesitas haremos uso del método `isin` que verifica si un conjunto de datos existe sobre el DataFrame o en una de sus columnas. Sin embargo al utilizar el resultado en una condición (por ejemplo sentencia `if`) ocurre una excepción como ya habrás podido notar, esto debido a que el resultado es una Serie de pandas o DataFrame, lo que quiere decir que contiene una matriz de booleanos, lo que provoca ambigüedad al no saber a que dato te refieres, eso se soluciona usando las funciones `all` o `any` (incluso `bool`), `all` devuelve `True` si todos los datos son `True` y `any` devuelve `True` cuando por lo menos un dato es `True`.

También usaremos la función `zip` para poder *"emparejar"* los datos y crear una estructura de un DataFrame para que pandas pueda interpretarlo y crearlo.

```py
def resultado_final(cedula, materia, calificacion, df_alumnos):
    if any(df_alumnos["Cedula"].isin(cedula)):
        data = zip(cedula, materia, calificacion)
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=["Cedula", "Materia", "Calificacion"])
        return df
    else: print("Datos incorrectos")
```

Esta función recibe 4 parámetros, los 3 primeros son información a cerca del alumno, estos datos deben ser listas (puedes introducir más de un dato en cada lista pero el número de elementos en cada una debe ser igual). El último parámetro es tu DataFrame de alumnos con el que  se hará la validación para verificar que el alumno exista. En este caso solo se corrobora la cédula, ya que es como un identificador.

Y lo usarías de esta forma:

```py
resultado = resultado_final([123], ["Matematica"], [8], df)
```

Como extra puedes añadir la columna de `Resultado` donde aparecerá `aprobado` o `desaprobado` según corresponda, esto se hará usando el método `apply` que aplicará una función sobre cada elemento de una columna del DataFrame.

```py
def resultado_final(cedula, materia, calificacion, df_alumnos):
    if any(df_alumnos["Cedula"].isin(cedula)):
        data = zip(cedula, materia, calificacion)
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=["Cedula", "Materia", "Calificacion"])
        df["Resultado"] = df["Calificacion"].apply(lambda x: "Aprobado" if x>=6 else "Desaprobado")
        return df
    else: print("Datos incorrectos")
```

Por lo que me dices en los comentarios, tu tendrás una lista de datos o un DataFrame y quieres que se ejecute la función con cada uno. Por lo tanto debemos modificar un poco la función, dado que si la dejamos tal y como está esta creará n DataFrames y dudo que sea lo que quieres.

```
global df_result #declaras como global
df_result=None

def resultado_final(cedula, materia, calificacion, df_alumnos):
    global df_result
    if any(df_alumnos["Cedula"].isin(cedula)):
        data = zip(cedula, materia, calificacion)
        if not df_result:
              df_result = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=["Cedula", "Materia", "Calificacion"])
        df_result["Resultado"] = df_result["Calificacion"].apply(lambda x: "Aprobado" if x>=6 else "Desaprobado")
        return df_result
    else: print("Datos incorrectos")
```

Ahora lo utilizarías igual que antes pero dentro de un bucle `for`. Por ejemplo.

```py
data = [
    [123, "Mateaticas", 9],
    [456, "Ingles", 9]
]

for cedula, materia, calif in data:
    resultado_final(cedula, materia, calif, df)
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134224/discussion-on-answer-by-christian-crear-dataframe-a-partir-de-una-lista).